# Exec stored procedure with table variable as parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does anyone know why this query doesn't work? How to add the table variable itemId as parameter to the exec statement? Thanks

```
DECLARE @test TABLE 
(
itemId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
finalAmount DECIMAL
);
     
INSERT INTO @test EXEC [GetItems] 

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)

DECLARE @param NVARCHAR(max)
SET @param = N'select itemId from @test'

SELECT @sql = 'EXEC [InsertTestItem]'+' ' + @param;
SELECT @sql
EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: The above code is product specific. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Hi jarlh is Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Why do you need dynamic SQL here at all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute stored procedure with table-valued parameter from SSMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240790/how-to-execute-stored-procedure-with-table-valued-parameter-from-ssms)

Comment: Table variables (like other variables) are scoped only to the current batch, since your dynamic sql executes in a different batch, it has no knowledge of the table variable. You can declare your tale variable within your dynamic SQL, or use a temporary table. As @Larnu has pointed out though, there is no need for dynamic SQL at all here. Your procedure `InsertTestItem` also looks pretty suspicious if it is genuinely taking a SQL Statement as a parameter, this is a huge code smell!

Comment: I am, in truth, more concerned that the parameter you are passing to `dbo.InsertTestItem` is `N'select itemId from @test'`; this implies you are passing a query string to the procedure and therefore this is very likely a *huge* security vulnerability.

Comment: It is also possible that `GetItems` should be a table valued function (inline if possible), or even a view since it has no parameters. Using stored procedures for selecting data ends up with issues exactly like this, where if you want to modify the resultset in anyway, the process becomes significantly more verbose. All things considered, this seems to have [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/179361) written all over it

Comment: What is the actual parameter type of `InsertTestItem`

Comment: @John was the answer any use?

Answer (score 0):

See a full working example in SQL Server, you should be able to run each block one after the other to see that its selected everything from your table type that you pass in to the stored proc

```
-- Create the Table type that we will use in the stored proc------------------------

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.types WHERE is_table_type = 1 AND name = 'MyIdTableType')
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Creating type [dbo].[MyIdTableType]'
    CREATE TYPE [dbo].MyIdTableType AS TABLE (
        Id BIGINT
    )
END 
GO

-- Create a stored proc that uses it ------------------------

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UsMyTabelType]
    @IdsTable AS [dbo].MyIdTableType Readonly
AS

BEGIN    
    -- Now you have the data you can use it like any normal table and join on it
    SELECT * FROM @IdsTable
END
GO

-- Lets test it out ------------------------

DECLARE @myIds AS MyIdTableType

INSERT INTO @myIds (Id) 
VALUES 
(1),
(2), 
(3)

EXEC dbo.UsMyTabelType @IdsTable = @myIds
```